# sorting array without php built-in sort function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am very newbie on programming, first studying PHP language about arrays. I can sort an array with `sort` function,  but I got stuck here.

If i have input `array(1,3,5,6,7,8,11,12,17,11)`
I try to get output `12` or  bigger number 2, but if I do `print_r($array[i] - 1);`
I just get `10-1=9`. how can i get value `12`?

and then if I have input `array(1,2,3,5,6)` I try to get output `false` because of the missing number 4.
I make sort function:

```
for(int j:0;j<=count($array) ;j++) {
   for(int i:0;i<=count($array[i+1]);i++{
      if($array[i]>$array[$+1]{
         $temp=$array[$i+1];
         $array[$i+1]=$array[$i];
         $array[$i]=temp;
      }
   }
}
print_r($array) ;
```

Thanks if someone can help me or teach me? :)

Comment: That is not how you write a `for` loop in PHP. This code should give you a syntax error.

Comment: Hi, if you are using the `sort()` function to sort the array, try adding a sort_flag as the second parameter such as this: `sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`. From what you are telling us is that your sort is sorting by strings instead of integers. The code example you provided is full of syntax errors too.

Comment: @WebCode.ie He's not using the built-in `sort` function, the loop he posted is his own sort code (I think it's a bubble sort).

Comment: In addition to the syntax errors, you also have a number of basic logic errors. The last element of an array is `count($array)-1`, so the loops should use `<`, not `<=`. `count($array[i+1])` makes no sense at all, since `$array[i+1]` is a number, not an array, so you can't count it.

Comment: You're missing lots of `$` before variable names. `int j:0` should just be `$j = 0` (this isn't C, you don't put type names before variable declarations).

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your code. Check the comments under your question, they pretty much covered it.

To sort an array with a custom sort you can use this:

```
$array = array(1,3,5,6,7,8,11,12,17,11);
$arrayCount = count($array);  // no need to evaluate the count on every iteration of the for loop

for($i=0; $i < $arrayCount - 1; $i++)
{
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $arrayCount; $j++)
    {
        // if you want the array sorted from bigger to smaller number use `>` here
        if($array[$j] < $array[$i])
        {
            $temp = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[$j];
            $array[$j] = $temp;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 3
  [2] => 5
  [3] => 6
  [4] => 7
  [5] => 8
  [6] => 11
  [7] => 11
  [8] => 12
  [9] => 17
)
```

Now to retrieve a desired value from the array or `false` if it does not exist you would write something like this using the built in `array_search()` method:

```
// Check if array contains a value 12, if it does return the index location in the array
// returns false if the value is not found
$index = array_search(12, $array); 

if($index === false)
{
    echo 'Value does not exist in the array.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Value '.$array[$index].' is at index '.$index.' in the array.';
}
```

Comment: i want get 12,because 12 is bigger number two in array,  can you help me?

Comment: @newbie I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want. You want to get 12 because of what?